# Maxima installation issue: maxima.core creation failed

Tags: installation, common-lisp, maxima

I was installing Maxima taking the following step-by-step instructions:

https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/INSTALL.lisp

Upon exiting and after step 9b I find that under the src/ directory a binary-sbcl/ dir was created (this was expected) but running the maxima executable throws the next error:

```
could not open file "/home/mydir/Documents/Soft/maxima-5.38.0/src/binary-sbcl/maxima.core"
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this same issue, here's the solution:

Be sure to follow every step. Sometimes when you are in step 9b and you exit the Maxima environment it won't actually create the maxima.core file where it needs to.

So, you'd want to follow these simple steps:

- Restart your Common Lisp environment.
- Repeat step 8.
- Now do `(maxima-dump)`

This should create maxima.core and you can run maxima without any issues.